# Going through dictionaries in a more efficient way

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that I am calling from PHP. The following loop is making my script to execute little slow. I have to display the stuff on browser. The `p` dictionary is quite large.

Is there any more efficient way I can write the below code?

```
for key, value in p.iteritems():
    for key1, value1 in value.iteritems():
        if value1['platform_name'] == name:
            lis.append(value1['full_external_id'])
```

Comment: It's not clear what this snippet is supposed to be doing. If you're calling this a lot, why not have a dictionary keyed by `name`?

Comment: I read this code as building a list of all external IDs mapped to a given name.  The dict keys are immaterial; each entry is a dictionary (JSON format?).

Comment: How often do you need to look up a given name?  If you have to return this list multiple times, @jonrsharpe is correct: use this loop to build a reference dictionary keyed by name.  Build the dictionary with your loop logic above.  Future references merely index the new dict by name.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Code Review

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dict inside a dict and for every I assume user details you want a certain key field. Try using [memcache](https://github.com/linsomniac/python-memcached) to ease this, you can set it to refresh every 5-10-60 min.